# Post on friend wall using iOS SDK 3.5 and native post dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, post, sdk

I would like to post on friend wall using the native post dialog and the latest 3.5 iOS SDK. It seems like Facebook simply didn't supply any method to handle this thing.

I am looking at this method (all the supplied methods with this signature:

```
[FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom...]
```

and see no way of posting on friend's wall.

Does anyone have some insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't post to a friends wall using the iOS share sheet, which is what presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom... is a wrapper around.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. If I cannot post with the integrated dialog on friends wall, so what is it for? Only for posting on my wall? What is the difference between posting on my wall and posting on a friend wall?

Comment: Yes, it's for posting to your timeline only. Posting to friend's timeline has been clamped down in general as it often results in negative feedback. There are some new ways to do this (via user mentions or friend tagging - available only for Open Graph stories) that gives friends the option of approving the tags before the story shows up on their timeline.